# How to wire up the outlets for a heavily nested ember.js route structure

Tags: ember.js

I have the following routes

```
App.Router.map(function(match) {
    this.route("days", { path: "/" });
    this.resource("day", { path: "/:day_id" }, function() {
        this.resource("slots", { path: "/slots" }, function() {
            this.resource("slot", { path: "/:slot_id" }, function() {
                this.route("edit", { path: "/edit" });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I have the following templates for the above

```
script/app/templates/application.handlebars
script/app/templates/days.handlebars
script/app/templates/day.handlebars
script/app/templates/day/index.handlebars
script/app/templates/slots.handlebars
script/app/templates/slots/index.handlebars
script/app/templates/slot.handlebars
script/app/templates/slot/index.handlebars
script/app/templates/slot/edit.handlebars
```

1. is the above correct
2. what html should be in each handlebars template if I plan to do the below (excluding days)
3. what routes do I need to define assuming I want to do the below (excluding days)

   - when a day is selected I want to show a list of associated models
     (slots in this case)
   - when a slot is selected I want the html from
     it's index page (showing an individual slot based on the slot id
     param being passed to the route)

**UPDATE**

So far it looks like the routes marked with "resource" need to have an {{outlet}} available for the inner resource or route to drop in some markup.

for example the day.handlebars template has an {{outlet}} and inside my day/index.handlebars template I drop in a for loop to show each day. Next inside the slots.handlebars template I include an {{outlet}} and inside the slots/index.handlebars template I add another for loop to show each available slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it goes

```
script/app/templates/application.handlebars - {{outlet}}
script/app/templates/days.handlebars - template, but it should be a `resource` 
                                       instead of a route, which results in this
script/app/templates/days/index.handlebars - will be rendered on `/days`


script/app/templates/day.handlebars - {{outlet}} inserted into `application` outlet
script/app/templates/day/index.handlebars - inserted into `day` outlet

script/app/templates/slots.handlebars - {{outlet}} inserted into `day` outlet
// this also overwrites `day/index` template, so only one of them 
// can be displayed at once

script/app/templates/slots/index.handlebars - inserted into `slots` outlet
script/app/templates/slot.handlebars - {{outlet}} inserted into `slots` outlet
script/app/templates/slot/index.handlebars - inserted into `slot` outlet
script/app/templates/slot/edit.handlebars - inserted into `slot` outlet
```

You should also probably define `days` as a resource

`this.resource("days", { path: "/" });`

It doesn't make any difference to the other routes, this route will still work

`this.resource("day", { path: "/:day_id" } ...`

Comment: awesome! thanks for the blazing quick reply! Any chance you could explain why "days" could be a resource in this case? I just assumed if it stood alone it should be a route (or is it as simple as you blog puts it "a resource is a thing" and "a route is something to do with the thing" ?

Comment: It should be a resource because it is representing a resource :) `NOTE: You should use this.resource for URLs that represent a noun, and this.route for URLs that represent adjectives or verbs modifying those nouns.` from http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_resources

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Jakub's answer - In case of nested resources, typically (when you want the child to be rendered over the parent) **xyz.handlebars** should contain just the outlet and whatever html you wanted to be part of xyz template should go into **xyz/index.handlebars**. That is because whenever you come back to the parent resource it will not be re-rendered, because ember assumes it to be present all the time. But siblings will always be re-rendered which in your case are slot/index and slot/edit

Regarding routes, anything that has to have a child will be a resource. In your case
**host/#/days** and **hosts/#/day** are both rendered into the application outlet